# right way to show span by jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a textbox and span within a table cell td. If the textbox contains an invalid character span will appear with a message. My problem is when the message (span) shows up the textbox will be moved to the left a bit even there is enough place in the td. Here is the code. How do I make it so that it is not moved to the left.

```
<td style="text-align:left;">
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtWSName" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
    <span class="grayUrl" id="wrongNameSpan" style="display:none">wrong character</span>
</td>
```

```
 $("#txtWSName").blur(function () {
     var value = $(this).attr("value");
     if (!IsValidName(value)) {
            $(this).addClass("missing");
            $("#wrongNameSpan").show("slow");
        }
 });
```

Comment: please make a jsfiddle with your html+js+css

Comment: instead of using .show() use .css('display', 'inline-block'). By using .show, jQuery changes the display to block thus making your span a whole block which explainx why it changes lines.

Comment: Your code works here though... http://jsfiddle.net/UuGxx/1/

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
<td style="text-align:left;">
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtWSName" runat="server" style="float:left"></asp:TextBox>
    <span class="grayUrl" id="wrongNameSpan" style="display:none; float:left;">wrong character</span>
</td>
```

If you still get an issue, then there could be a problem with width, padding, margin of TD or input or SPAN